# Why do I have a `~/texmf` directory?

Tags: directory

Shortly after setting up `emacs` with `auctex` I noticed that a directory `~/texmf` on my system. Issuing `$ tree ~/texmf` returns

```
~/texmf
|- web2c
   |- tlmgr.log
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this directory exists and what the file `tlmgr.log` does. In particular, I'm curious what the effects of deleting the directory would be.

Comment: Rename the directory to something else and see who's creating the folder by running the suspected programs one by one

Comment: TeX metafont ? are you using TeX or LaTeX ?

Comment: I'm using LaTeX... Maybe this question is more appropriate on the TeX stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66614/change-texmfhome-per-user

This tells you how to change the location (and name) of the directory. It also gives an explanation of the reason it exists.